# How to customize the SMTP message

Tags: 7, emails

When a message is send to the user a message like this is shown to him :

[message screenshot](http://prntscr.com/bwwr4q)

[image]

> SMTP -> FROM SERVER: ........... 
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER: .......
>   ............................................................................
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER: .......
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER: ......
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER: .....................
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER: ................................
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER: .....................................
>   Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address.

I only want the last one: "Further instructions have been sent ..." to show. Is it also possible to personalize it ?

Comment: Are you using the SMTP module for mail delivery?

Comment: yes i'm using the module SMTP Authentication Support and phpmailer

Comment: Did you try disabling the debug messages in the SMTP module settings?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bx0glk i try this but i still got the the same message

Comment: Do you have the devel module enabled?

Comment: No http://prntscr.com/bx16sx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative method to solve my prob by using this two modules: [Disable Messages Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) and [String Overrides Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)

Answer (score 2):

Those messages are shown as the result of enabling logging in the SMTP module. It's only [set once](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/smtp/tree/smtp.mail.inc?h=7.x-1.4#n72) from the `smtp_debugging` variable. If it's still logging after disabling it, you to debug the issue as there's no one cause (e.g. caching, forcing the setting in **settings.php**/**settings.local.php**, code base hack, etc.) and is out of scope of Q&A.

As for altering the "Further instructions have..." message, there are many ways to do this (e.g. form alter, translation files), but the simplest is probably utilizing the [String Overrides module](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) which will let you override any message wrapped in a [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7.x) function.